# vba erro em tempo de execução '-2147221164 (80040154)': Classe não registrada

Tags: vba, vb.net, visual-basic-6, visual-studio-2019

eu fiz uma biblioteca de classes no visual studio 2019 usando o .NET framework que é registrada para interoperabilidade COM e gera um arquivo (.tlb). Ela foi programada em VB.NET e possui uma classe simples com um método simples (classe calcular, método Soma):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi possível incluir o arquivo tlb como referência no VBA onde tenho um código que usa métodos dessa classe para dar ação a um botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, ao executar acontece o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico em depurar ele aponta para a instância da classe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao consultar o Stack encontrei outras pessoas com o mesmo problema mas sem solução:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570140/adodb-connection-in-vb6-open-method-fails-with-runtime-error-2147221164-8004
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239548/vba-selenium-class-not-registered-80040154

Já efetuei um reparo no meu office chegando a desinstalar a instalar denovo, poderiam me ajudar a solucionar esse erro que impede a execução da minha biblioteca no excel VBA?

Comment: É necessário usar 'calculadora' pra encontra o obj 'calcular' visto que esse arquivo já foi colocado como referência?

Comment: Em uma das tentativas eu retirei o 'calculadora' deixando assim: Dim objCalc As calcular/ Set objCalc = New calcular mas o erro permaneceu ...